# Auto-layout on a View for a Navigation Bar's title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, nslayoutconstraint

I have a simple class that creates a `UIView` containing a label. I want to use that view as the central section of a `UINavigationBar`, with 2 buttons on either side. The code below works well without adding the label:

```
class myView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

I call the class so:

```
let avatar = UIBarButtonItem(image: avatarImage, ...)
let otherButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: otherImage, ...)

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems  = [avatar]
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [otherButton]

let headerTitle = myView(frame: .zero)
headerTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
navigationItem.titleView = headerTitleView
```

But if I add the label inside the UIView:

```
class myView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = .green

        let theLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        theLabel.text = "The Title"
        theLabel.textAlignment = .center
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(theLabel!)
    }
}
```

.. I see the label, but it is stuck to the far left of the view. If I try to add constraints to the label, something like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    theLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
    theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
])
```

.. it crashes, since the size of self (the UIView) is still .zero.

I've tried various combinations of `layoutIfNeeded()` and `sizeToFit()`, but with no success so far. How do I place a view as a title for a navigation bar, and layout elements inside that view?

Comment: hi! did you try calling sizeToFit() after setting the text of your label? That helped me when I tried to place a label in my navigation bar

Comment: Yes @joliejuly, I put `theLabel.sizeToFit()` right after setting the text; it made no difference - still in upper left corner.

Comment: what crash ........................

Comment: @Sh_Khan: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`  (a signal SIGABRT)

Comment: please share all console log temporarily

Comment: also, in what moment do you call NSLayoutConstraint.activate for the label?

Comment: @joliejuly: I call the `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` immediately following `theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in the above code.

Comment: this is the problem you need to set constraints after addSubview

Comment: @Sh_Khan: there is no other console log messages at all. I do stop program execution just before the `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` line, and see that the frame for `self` (the UIView) is (0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: <sigh> Yes, you both are right, @joliejuly & @Sh_Khan.  Interestingly, the `UIView.backgroundcolor` is lost doing this - but a minor problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guees it's an order error

```
self.addSubview(theLabel) // first
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([  // then second
  theLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
  theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
])
```